# getloadavg() related to the number of CPU, exceeds 100%

Tags: python, psutil

I am following the [psutil doc](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get the average system load over the last 1 minute. I am using the `[x / psutil.cpu_count() * 100 for x in psutil.getloadavg()]`, rounded to 1 decimal place (i.e. `[round(x / psutil.cpu_count() * 100, 1) for x in psutil.getloadavg()]`).

Sometimes I get values exceeding 100% (e.g. 120% - 130%), does that make any sense or it is because of the `round`?

**EDIT**

I just realised that the `Hyper Thread CPUs are excluded` which could result in >100%, right?

Answer (score 1):

I see exactly the same behaviour. `round()` is not causing the problem.
`psutil.cpu_count()` already returns number of physical + logical CPU's. So Hyper Threading is already taken into account.
I suspect `psutil.getloadavg()`having an issue. Or I got something wrong from their documentation, although it is actually clearly described: [psutil docs: getloadavg()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.getloadavg)